# I want to get input from in ruby from a user, and after they press <Enter>, I want to print additional text on the same line

Tags: ruby

Using Ruby, I want to prompt the user for example "Continue (Y/N) : "
When they enter "Y" and press enter, I want to print "es" on the same line.
The completed line should look like this:
**Continue (Y/N) : Yes**

Unfortunately, 'gets' not only includes the carriage return in the data (which can be filtered out with .chomp), but it also echoes it to the screen resulting in undesired output such as :
**Continue (Y/N) : Y

es**

Is there another way to get input that does not echo the final carriage return to the screen?  I don't care if it shows up in the variable thanks to .chomp.

Comment: Try IO#getch or look at the expect library.

Comment: It looks like that might do the trick - thanks for the suggestion, @todd A. Jacobs.  Too bad 'gets' doesn't have a flag.  I think I remember reading that you could change the terminator character, but that doesn't help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

### Looping Over Character IO

Here's a working example that uses [io/console](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/IO.html#class-IO-label-Extension+io-2Fconsole) to handle single-character input without echoing the character to the terminal. For simplicity, it's done in a loop that also allows you to exit early with CTRL-C as a `case` match rather than using Signal#trap or rescuing SignalException, and re-prompts if an invalid character is entered.

Since one supposes you may want to use the character somewhere else, this example saves the upcased character in the *@char* instance variable. If you don't want to use an instance variable then you could do something inline or capture the value from #getch by assigning the value of `break char` instead.

The following works for me on Ruby 3.2.1:

```rb
require "io/console"

loop do
  $stdout.print "Continue (Y/N): "
  @char = $stdin.getch.upcase

  case @char
  when "Y" then puts "#{@char}es"
  when "N" then puts "#{@char}o"
  when "\u0003" then
    puts
    $stderr.puts "Caught CTRL-C; exiting loop."
    break
  else
    puts
    $stderr.puts "invalid key: #{@char.inspect}"
    next
  end

  break
end

printf "@char=%p\n", @char
```

### Results of Entering Various Characters

This produces the following results when passed <kbd>RETURN</kbd>, `y`, `n`, and <kbd>^C</kbd>.

```
Continue (Y/N): 
invalid key: "\r"
Continue (Y/N):
```

```
Continue (Y/N): Yes
@char="Y"
```

```
Continue (Y/N): No
@char="N"
```

```
Continue (Y/N): 
Caught CTRL-C; exiting loop.
@char="\u0003"
```